# Google Drive permissions via Apps Script -- Is it possible to prevent an editor from downloading or printing a sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet that I want to let someone edit, but I don't want them to be able to download, print, or copy the spreadsheet.

AFAIK, this is not possible to do via the regular Drive or Sheets UI. Is there any way to do it using Apps Script?

Comment: You can disable download, print and copy options for commentators and viewers.

Comment: ...........Nope